# How do I make contents of nav appear when a div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I haven't wrote my own custom Java script before so I need some help.

I have a div with the class "bt-menu" and then a navigation menu in nav tags.

I need a script that slides the contents of the nav in from the left when the div is clicked. And then the nav to slide back into the left when the div or anywhere else on the screen is pressed.

Hope someone can help, thanks

Comment: Could you post your HTML code you have?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for fancy jQuery or even JavaScript here, the CSS [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and `tabindex` can do this for us:

```css
div{
  background-color:red;
}
nav{
  position:absolute;
  left:-100%;
  transition:left 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
div:focus + nav{
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0">
  <p>Click in this div</p>
</div>
<nav>
  <a>Page1</a>
  <a>Page2</a>
  <a>Page3</a>
  <a>Page4</a>
  <a>Page5</a>
</nav>
```

However this relies on `div` being defined before `nav` in the code.

Comment: This didn't work, take a look at my new question for the code I currently have :D  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936516/how-do-i-make-nav-slide-in-on-click-of-div