# How do i make <nav> slide in on click of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I need something that will make the nav contents slide out from the left when the div class "bt-menu" is pressed. It also needs to slide back in to the left when the div is clicked again, or anywhere outside of the nav is clicked.

There are sub menus in the main nav ,as you can see in the code below, this means that I need to be able to click a LI with the class "submenu" and have the list inside it slide down from underneath it.

Sorry I cant figure out how to show you the css I have.

```
<header>
    <div class="menu_bar">
        <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="submenu" >
                <a href="#">Nielsen Products<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">Exterior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Interior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Odour Control & Air Fresheners<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Exterior Finishes<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dressings<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Glass Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Workshop Maintenance<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Janitorial<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TDS & SDS INFO<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nielsen Catalogue</a></li>
            <li class="submenu">
                <a href="#">Equipment/Tools/Consumables<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">Valeting, Brushes and Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tools & Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Workshop Consumables<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">AdBlue<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Hope you can help, thanks

Comment: Check this out http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/

Comment: Where is the JS code that you tried so far?

Comment: `code` $(document).ready(main);

var counter = 1;

function main () {
 $(".menu_bar").click(function(){
  if (counter == 1) {
   $("nav").animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   counter = 0;
  } else {
   counter = 1;
   $("nav").animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
  }
 }); 
 $(".submenu").click(function(){
  $(this).children(".children").slideToggle();
 });
}   `code`

Comment: Recommend you put up a demo at jsfiddle or codepen.io. It's kind of hard to tell from this what you've tried, and where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is:

```
$(".bt-menu").click(function(){  $("nav").slideToggle(); });
```

I edit the code you can check it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$(".bt-menu").click(function(){  $("nav").slideToggle(); });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
    <div class="menu_bar">
        <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="submenu" >
                <a href="#">Nielsen Products<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">Exterior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Interior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Odour Control & Air Fresheners<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Exterior Finishes<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dressings<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Glass Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Workshop Maintenance<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Janitorial<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TDS & SDS INFO<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Nielsen Catalogue</a></li>
            <li class="submenu">
                <a href="#">Equipment/Tools/Consumables<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">Valeting, Brushes and Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tools & Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Workshop Consumables<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">AdBlue<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".bt-menu").click(function(){  $("nav").slideToggle(); });

  });
</script>
    <header>
        <div class="menu_bar">
            <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-menu"></span>Menu</a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="submenu" >
                    <a href="#">Nielsen Products<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a href="#">Exterior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interior Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Odour Control & Air Fresheners<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Exterior Finishes<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dressings<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Glass Cleaning<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Workshop Maintenance<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Janitorial<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TDS & SDS INFO<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Nielsen Catalogue</a></li>
                <li class="submenu">
                    <a href="#">Equipment/Tools/Consumables<span class="icon-arrow-down2"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a href="#">Valeting, Brushes and Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tools & Equipment<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Workshop Consumables<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AdBlue<span class="icon-dot-single"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/light/

Comment: I copied this code and it still didn't work, I only want it to slide in when the screen is smaller than a certain size. I have a nav menu working for a laptop but I cant get the button working for when the screen size decreases.

Comment: I added a script tag in the head with the jquery code.

Comment: for checking is your website ruining on mobile device you can use this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: if you use chrome press shift+cnt+i and then copy console log here

Comment: I have this in my head is that it? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: I use internet explorer, not chrome

Comment: in chrome go to menu then more tools then developer tools.

Comment: I don't use chrome, I use internet explorer

Comment: you can also press f12

Comment: this is all that show up "File: nav.html"

Comment: this is problems that you may have: 1) you didnt add jquery 2) add this script before jquery loaded.

Comment: I added the jquery so how do I know if I did the second problem?

Comment: make sure the script tag for running slidetoggle is placed after the script for adding jquery

Comment: this add jquery to your page <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: can you send me the whole head section of the code in the correct order so I can make sure it is definitely right please

Comment: They are definitely in the right order so I don't know what is wrong

Comment: i updated the code. use it :).

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the sliding bit to work but when the webpage is first loaded the menu is open and I would like it to start closed.

Comment: add $("nav").slideToggle(); before $(".bt-menu").click...

Comment: IT WORKS! The only thing I wouldn't mind being fixed is when you load the page for the first time, you can see the nav being toggled shut, is there anyway of it just being shut without you having to watch it close? Maybe in the CSS?

Comment: add this to your css file nav {display:none}

Comment: That fixed it but I Just found another problem. It is making the nav toggle on the laptop version to but I just want it to toggle on mobile version. I only edited the nav css after the media query